# sql update integer type

Tags: c#, sql

There is something wrong with the following update query.

```
string sql = "update Car set plate = '" + textBox2.Text + "' , color='"
           + textBox3.Text + "' , model='"+textBox5.Text+ "' , year= "
           + textBox4.Text;
sql += " where carid= " + textBox1.Text;

int res = CarDatabase.executeOthers(sql);
if (res > 0)
{
    string sql2 = "select * from Car";
    DataTable dt = CarDatabase.executeSelect(sql2);
    mainframe.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully");
}
```

Actually, I encounter the same problem when I add year to my query. Why? :S

Comment: SQL Injection Attacks go!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: What's the error or effect / output? And what is the expected effect?

Comment: Knowing what the problem actually is would be helpful. i.e. What error is thrown, are too few rows updated, too many rows?

Comment: Mmm.... i dont really see how do you think we can help you, you dont tell nothing, erro? what is wrong?, so on...

Comment: it say update statement is wrong :s

Comment: Sql Injection is possible + bad performance because you using no parameterized queries that will result in different execution plans.

Comment: It does not work probably because *you have already been hacked* !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that one of your TextBoxes probably has content that is breaking this. The better answer is to never, ever write a query this way because it is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You need to look at how to do parameterized queries.

Start by reading the [How to: Execute a Parameterized Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738521.aspx) article on MSDN.